# Different frame rated on path

Tags: camera

I have a camera following a path. Ive set it at 600 frames. Half way into the path can i extend the frame rate? And then back to the normal rate ive set.

Consider it a slo mo effect.

Comment: I assume you're wanting the camera to proceed normally along a path up to the 300th frame where you then slow it down (or even stop) for say a hundred frames, then have it proceed on to the end of the path?  If so you would need to extend the overall number of frames to allow more frames (time) for the cam to proceed past the 400 frame mark at the original speed.

Comment: yeah I figured but this then slows the WHOLE frame time. My only solution is to have frames at whatever and then import the mp4 into premiere pro and edit the speed/duration accordingly